# Что быстрее? Сравнение хешей или побайтовое

Tags: java

Что будет быстрее? Сравнить 128 элементов побайтово или их одноразово сгененый хеш(к примеру хеш int 6-12 элементов или длина числа в ширь:))? также с 6 элементами массива аналогичный вопрос.

Ожидается объяснение и какой-нибудь быстрый алгоритм генерирования хеша(в случае их быстроты).

Comment: С хешем возможны коллизии (два разных элемента могут иметь одинаковый хеш), это допускает задача?

Comment: Смотря сколько байт в кеше и в байтах

Comment: вы хотите найти одинаковые наборы данных? или вы решаете какую-нибудь другую задачу?

Comment: Я хочу сравнить два массива Х длин. Хеш байт? (6-12). Да я слышал что возможны коллизии(возможен и такой вариант)